# Eclipse Plugin isEnabled getEditor Infinite Loop

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, infinite-loop, stack-trace

I am developing an eclipse plugin.

I want to only enable a button on the toolbar when a certain file type is active in the editor.  Seeming easily enough, I used the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    if(FileGetter.getCurrentEditorFile().getFileExtension().equals("jvw"))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

In this example, "getCurrentEditorFile()" gets the active editor via PlatformUI and so on.

While running eclipse, this works perfectly! Switching files in the editor causes the button to enable/disable as files with different extensions selected.

However, upon closing eclipse, it gives hundreds of lines of error tracing, seemingly in a loop.

The error trace (some of it) can be found here --> http://pastebin.com/X4pe1n4b

I believe that when the isEnabled is called, it gets the editor (to check the file extension) which then causes the button isEnabled to trigger again, forming an infinite loop.

If this is correct however, I don't see why it would only happen upon closing eclipse and not during general use.

I know this is a vague question (sorry, stack overflow) but, any vague ideas / suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you!
Also, feel free to ask more, if you wish.

Comment: FileGetter.getCurrentEditorFile at line 33 is trying to open a message dialog which looks like it is causing the recursion. If this is to handle an error throw an exception and handle in in higher level code.

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you, you are correct.  The MessageDialog is causing the problem.  I tried throwing an error instead, which went as high as possible, however, it did not solve the problem.  Luckily, I've realised that because of the isEnabled, it shouldn't be possible to press the button and therefore an error message isn't actually needed.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Quite interestingly, when printing to the console instead, It prints the error 37 times but, doesn't form an infinite loop of errors.  It's interesting that this is called so many times while eclipse is closing down.  Thank you for the help!